# How to test a react component with props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to test a react components with props mounts ok and renders its content such as paras and divs correctly. My code can be found below or in this [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mouezk?file=index.js)

I tried testing it with a default prop but that didn't work.

```
import React from 'react';
import test from 'tape';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';


test('testing', t => {


  t.doesNotThrow(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<App2 txt={ok}/>);
  }, 'Should mount');


  t.end();
});
```

And this is my component with props.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import App from './index'

export default class App2 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {txt}=this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <p>hi {txt}</p> 
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the outer component supplying the prop.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import App2 from './app2'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
        <App2 txt={this.state.name}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you would do something like providing the properties yourself and ensuring that it renders with them:

```
test('test your component', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App2 txt={'michaelangelo'} />);

  expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).toEqual('hi michaelangelo');
});
```

You shouldn't worry about testing the  and html elements like that, but rather the props that you pass and that they render in the right place i.e., in the p tag